# Python trig problems

Tags: python, trigonometry, pythonista

Im using Pythonista 2 on my IPhone, and I'm trying to create a touch joystick. Its a simple concept, I touch somewhere on my screen, the joystick and the boundary snap to that position. Then, when I move my finger, the boundary stays still but the joystick inside moves, until i get to the edge of the boundary, then it follows on the circumference of the circle in between the center of the boundary and my finger. Here is the code:

```
def touch_moved(self, touch):
    global r
    r = 90
    l = (touch.location-c[0],touch.location-c[1])
    a = math.degrees(math.tan(l[1]/l[0]))
    if (touch.location[0] - c[0])**2 + (touch.location[1] - c[1])**2 < r**2:
        self.joystick.position = touch.location
    else:
        self.joystick.position = ((math.cos(a)*r)+c[0],(math.sin(a)*r)+c[1])`
```

But the joystick spazzes out on the circumference, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're using `a` as a parameter to `sin` and `cos`, but it came from a call to `math.degrees()`; trig functions always operate on radians, not degrees.
2. `a` is derived from the result of a call to `tan`, which should be a warning sign: `tan` uses an angle as input, not normally as an output.  You probably want the inverse function here, `atan`.  Actually, what you really want is `math.atan2()`, which takes the horizontal and vertical values as separate parameters.  As your code is written, you will get a divide-by-zero error if the touch position is directly above or below the center point.
3. Your calculation of `l` seems wrong - shouldn't you be using indexes `[0]` and `[1]` with `touch.location`, like you're doing two lines later?